# Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.. Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular-cli

Estoy iniciando en esto de Angular 2 y lo que quiero es interrogar una API rest con Angular 2 Typescript, usando Angular-cli, por ello creé un servicio un modelo y un componente para interrogar a la api.

> Componente

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {LiguesServices} from '../services/ligues.services'
import { ligueModel } from '../models/ligueModel'
@Component({
    selector:'ligues',
    templateUrl: '../templates/ligues.component.html',
    moduleId: module.id
})

export class liguesComponent implements OnInit{

    public liguesList : Array<ligueModel> = [];

    constructor(private service:LiguesServices){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.service.getLigues().subscribe(
            data => {this.liguesList = data;},
            error => {alert('Error');})

    }
}
```

> HTML

```
<h2>Ligues de Football</h2>
<p>Liste de ligues</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6" *ngFor="let item of liguesList ">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="../images/football-header.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">{{item.caption}}</span>
          <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>{{item.league}}, {{item.year}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>{{liguesList}}</p>
```

> Servicio

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/Operator/map';
import { ligueModel } from '../models/ligueModel'


@Injectable()
export class LiguesServices{
    constructor(public http: Http){}

    getLigues():Observable<ligueModel[]>{
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        return this.http.get('http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/?season=2017', {headers: headers})
        .map((res:any) => res.json() as ligueModel[]);
    }
}
```

> Modelo

```
export class ligueModel{
    public ligueID: number;
    public captation: string;
    public league: string;
    public year: string;
    public currentMatchDay:number;
    public numberOfMatchday: number;
    public numberofTeams: number;
    public numberofGames: number;
    public lastUpdated: string;
}
```

pero tengo errores al momento de ejecutar
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/?season=2017. (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-headers’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

Estoy usando Mozilla como navegador de prueba

Comment: Revisa qué headers está enviando el browser en la petición. Por lo que dice el error, está enviando un header que no está en la "lista blanca" (ej `accept`, o  `X-Requested-With`) en donde sólo aceptas `Content-Type`. Además, al ser cross origin probablemente envía una petición de tipo `OPTIONS` como preflight y tú sólo estás permitiendo las peticiones `GET`.

Comment: de hecho estoy pidiendo datos a la API y si necesito hacer un GET

Comment: Claro, pero puedes aceptar múltiples tipos de verbos, al menos OPTIONS junto con GET

Answer (score 2):

Posiblemente te esta bloqueando al hacer una petición a un servidor externo, por CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) tienes que decir de que servidor aceptas la información.

```
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'accept', 'Content-Type');
```

Fuente: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665056/angularjs-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-readi)